# Removing UITableViewCell Selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Currently I'm overriding the standard UITableViewSelectionStyle by using `UITableViewSelectionStyleNone` and then changing the color the cell based on delegate methods:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
      didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];                
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"indexpath: %i",indexPath.row);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

This almost works except that whenever I highlight a cell and then drag my finger off of it without actually selecting it, the color doesn't change to white...if I set it to [UIColor RedColor] it works perfeclty. Why is this...

**Edit:**

Somehow when I print out the indexPath.row after didUnhlightRowAtIndexPath I get  "indexpath: 2147483647" from my NSLog

Comment: indexPath `2147483647` is equivalent to `NSNotFound`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could try:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

if you just want the highlight to go away after selecting a cell. Unless I misunderstand your question.

Answer (score 23):

You can also try this

```
tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
```

another way of doing this

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

one more

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also do it from the storyboard. Select the tableViewCell and under Attributes Inspector you can choose Selection > None

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [Swift 2 version](https://gist.github.com/cybertk/2befc00818c1ea6227fc)

```
    if let indexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        for indexPath in indexPaths {
            self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Unselect selected row(s). You do not even need to know which one it is.

```
tableView.selectRow(at: nil, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
```

Answer (score 2):

By maintaing a local instance of my indexPath, I was able to find the last selected cell and change its color to whitecolor. Seems really annoying that I have to maintain state myself, but it is what it is...

Comment: not sure why I got a downvote...just explaining how I solved my own problem for the benefit of others on Stack...

Comment: Yeah I feel your pain and hate it when that happens.. +1 for both your question and answer my friend :)

Comment: You don't have to maintain the state. UITableView has the method `indexPathsForSelectedRows`

Answer (score 1):

How about doing this with an extension?

```
import UIKit

extension UITableView {
    func removeRowSelections() {
        self.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.forEach {
            self.deselectRow(at: $0, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
tableView.removeRowSelections()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution that worked for me **(Swift 4.2)**
(if you still want table view's row to be selectable)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let index = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: index, animated: true)
    }
}
```